# Configure firewall to protect my laravel database from ransomware attack?

Tags: database, laravel, firewall

Recently, my laravel database was hacked and asked bitcoin 0.8 in return.
I want to apply firewall on database, so that database is not directly accessed by anyone outside.

I do not know to configure firewall in laravel.

If you have any answer. Please reply.

thanks.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: i think you put your hole application public

Comment: Protecting your database has nothing to do with Laravel. Unless they got in somewhere through your application.